# Testing if items have been fetched using "every" is not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I'm fetching new markers. And I'm testing if they have been fetched based on their id:

```
// newMarkers = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2}]
// state.fetchedMarkers = [{ id: 1 }]

newMarkers.forEach(marker => {
  if (state.fetchedMarkers.every(fetchedMarker => fetchedMarker.id === marker.id)) {
    console.log('newMarkers HAVE BEEN fetched')
  } else {
    console.log('newMrakers HAVEN'T BEEN fetched')
    state.fetchedMarkers.concat(newMarkers)
    // they haven't been fetched so I'm putting them in the fetched array
  }
})
```

But not matter what I do, "HAVE BEEN fetched" is always run and "HAVEN'T BEEN fetched" never runs.

Maybe there's something wrong with my if statement? Or maybe `every` isn't the right choice here?

Comment: What does the array look like when they haven't been fetched? (If `fetchedMarkers` is empty, there won't be any iterations, and nothing to test)

Comment: you should use some instead of every.

Comment: Might want to fix that apostrophe in a string for a start, other than that the code looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let newMarkers = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2}]
let fetchedMarkers = [{ id: 1 }]

newMarkers.forEach(marker => {
  if (fetchedMarkers.every(fetchedMarker => fetchedMarker.id === marker.id)) {
    console.log('newMarkers HAVE BEEN fetched')
  } else {
    console.log('newMrakers HAVENT BEEN fetched')
    fetchedMarkers.concat(newMarkers)
    // they haven't been fetched so I'm putting them in the fetched array
  }
})
```

Either the code you've shared is not complete or values of `newMarkers` and `fetchedMarkers` are incomplete, both of the `if` and `else` are running using the code you've provided. Just click `Run code snippet`

Comment: If you set value of fetchedMarkers = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }] then it will log "newMrakers HAVENT BEEN fetched" "newMrakers HAVENT BEEN fetched".

Answer (score 1):

Using fetchedMarkers.every will check for every object to match with the id. So if fetchedMarkers array has more values than 1, it will give wrong answer. Replacing fetchedMarkers.every to fetchedMarkers.some will work perfectly.

```js
let newMarkers = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2}]
let fetchedMarkers = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 3 }]

newMarkers.forEach(marker => {
  if (fetchedMarkers.some(fetchedMarker => fetchedMarker.id === marker.id)) {
    console.log('newMarkers HAVE BEEN fetched')
  } else {
    console.log('newMrakers HAVENT BEEN fetched')
    fetchedMarkers.concat(newMarkers)
    // they haven't been fetched so I'm putting them in the fetched array
  }
})
```